# Predict Huffman compression ratio without constructing the tree

Tags: algorithm, compression, huffman-code

I have a binary file and i know the number of occurrences of every symbol in it. I need to predict the length of compressed file IF i was to compress it using Huffman algorithm. I am only interested in the hypothetical output length and not in the codes for individual symbols, so constructing Huffman tree seems redundant.
As an illustration i need to get something like 
"A binary string of 38 bits which contains 4 a's, 5 b's and 10 c's can be compressed down to 28 bits.", except both the file and the alphabet size are much larger.

The basic question is: can it be done without constructing the tree?

Looking at the greedy algorithm: http://www.siggraph.org/education/materials/HyperGraph/video/mpeg/mpegfaq/huffman_tutorial.html

it seems the tree can be constructed in n*log(n) time where n is the number of distinct symbols in the file. This is not bad asymptotically, but requires memory allocation for tree nodes and does a lot of work which in my case goes to waste.

Comment: Did you mean a string of 28 *bytes*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the lower bound on the average number of bits per symbol in compressed file is nothing but the entropy `H = -sum(p(x)*log(p(x)))` for all symbols x in input. `P(x) = freq(x)/(filesize)`. Using this `compressed length(lower bound)  =  filesize*H`. This is the lower bound on compressed size of file. But unfortunately the optimal entropy is not achievable in most case because bits are integral not fractional so in practical case the huffman tree is needed to be constructed to get correct compression size. But optimal compression size can be used to get the upper bound on amount of compression possible and to decide whether to use huffman or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can upper bound the average bit counts per symbol in Huffman coding by
**H(p1, p2, ..., pn) + 1** where **H** is entropy, each **pi** is probability of symbol **i** occuring in input. If you multiply this value by input size **N** it will give you approximated length of encoded output.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily modify the algorithm to build the binary tree in an array. The root node is at index 0, its left node at index 1 and right node at index 2. In general, a node's children will be at `(index*2) + 1` and `(index * 2) + 2`. Granted, this still requires memory allocation, but if you know how many symbols you have you can compute how many nodes will be in the tree. So it's a single array allocation.

I don't see where the work that's done really goes to waste. You have to keep track of the combining logic *somehow*, and doing it in a tree as shown is pretty simple. I know that you're just looking for the final answer--the length of each symbol--but you can't get that answer without doing the work.

Comment: i think the OP needs space efficiency but binary tree in array is more inefficient as if huffman is doing bad then the tree will be right aligned or left aligned hence index will need a exponential size of array

Comment: @VikramBhat: True, the tree could require `n` levels in degenerate cases, which would mean `2^n` nodes, most of which are empty.