# Identify more Compressible Dataset by observing Input distribution

Tags: algorithm, compression, huffman-code, lossless-compression

This may be a repeat of the question here: [Predict Huffman compression ratio without constructing the tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24172313/predict-huffman-compression-ratio-without-constructing-the-tree?rq=1)

So basically, I have the probabilistic distribution of two datasets with the same variables but different probabilities. Now, is there any way that by looking at the variable distribution, I can to some degree confidently say that the dataset, when passed through a Huffman Coding implementation would achieve a higher compression ratio than the other?

One of the solutions that I came across was to calculate the upper bound using conditional entropy and then compute the average code length. Is there any other approach that can I can probably explore before using the said method?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why would you try to avoid to create the tree? It's quite fast to create and to calculate the size of the compressed data (without actually encoding it) is O(n) after you have the tree. O(n logn) is hard to beat with a good estimation of the compression ratio.

Comment: Yes, I do agree and I would most probably do the same but suppose there was a way that I could arrive at a good estimation of the depth of the tree or probably the number of nodes in the tree in order to estimate the average code length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what "to some degree confidently" means, but you can get a lower bound on the compressed size of each set by computing the zero-order entropy as done in the linked question (the negative of the sum of the probabilities times the log of the probabilities). Then the lower entropy very likely produces a shorter Huffman coding than the higher entropy. It is not definite, as I am sure that one could come up with a counter-example.

You also need to send a description of the code itself if you want to decode it on the other end, which adds a wrinkle to the comparison. However if the data is much larger than the code description, then that will be lost in the noise.

Simply generating the code, the coded data, and the code description is very fast. The best solution is to do that, and compare the resulting number of bits directly.

Comment: I don't have any reason not to generate the Huffman tree for both the datasets, I just wanted to see if there was a 'professional/cleaner' way to carry out the task. I am most likely to go ahead with the entropy method. Thanks.